# Is that good practice to do other things during db transaction?

Tags: database, transactions

During a database transaction, I want to do a few of other things - for example, query ElasticSearch and then write the result to other db table, before committing the transaction, it makes logic sense that I want the entire process in the same transaction, ether all succeed or fail, but I'm not sure if this is doable and good practice. if not, is there any suggestion of good practice in this scenario? Thanks

I think this is a general question and I'm using postgresql if that's any helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BEGIN` and `SAVEPOINT` to control the transactions.
Here is the documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/tutorial-transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

That's an excellent question, unfortunately there's no straight answer. It all depends. Let me give you some examples with how I'd suggest approaching:

1. Fetch extra data during transaction:

```
a\ save data in DB
b\ fetch some extra data (rollback in case there's fail here)
c\ save extra data in DB
```

This makes some sense, the whole operation seems like an atomic transaction. But consider the reasons for fail in c. If this data is not available - ok. But if the fails was a temporary network issue? Depending on your business, you might prefer to move b/ after the transaction, maybe even async job and fill the data later?

2. Saving extra data during transaction:

```
a\ save some data
b\ save data in an external system
c\ do some more stuff, commit transaction
```

This is more tricky. What if b\ was succesfull, but there was a fail between b\ and c? How do you rollback changes made in b?

There are probably more, I just wanted to show the way you might think about it.

My gut feeling tells me that the less happens inside the transaction, the easier it should be to reason about what is happening. If you find yourself debugging such weird scenarios - maybe it's reasonable investment to remodel your app so you're able to do those extra calls outside the transaction.